# .htaccess redirect for desktop but not working for mobile browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

I can't understand where the problem is. As suggested by the [hosting site](https://www.register.it/assistenza/redirect-http-https/) i use i have an .htaccess file that allows me to redirect from http to https, and on desktop it seems to work quite well. However on mobile no browser redirects correctly, can someone enlighten me?

This is the content of the htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines of code instead.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This does always work for me.

Comment: Nothing to do, it doesn't work for mobile

Comment: Can you send a link to the site?

Comment: Sure www.danielecadicina.it

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Could you specify which version of apache the server is running?

Comment: Do you have any apache logs files? If so could you please send a copy of it?

Comment: No, the site I use for hosting doesn't offer me any of that.

Comment: Try to use my other answer where you use php.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be changing your index.html file into and PHP file. By changing the file extension.

Then add the following lines at the top of the file:

```
<?php
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === "off") {
    $location = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $location);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying but nothing has changed

Comment: Seems like you accidentally added a space between <? and php.

Comment: Nothing to do, no one else has ideas?